# How can I install GNOME or GTK+ 3.6 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: gnome, gtk3

Is it possible to install GNOME 3.6 or gtk+ 3.6 on Ubuntu 12.04? If yes, how?

I want to write an application which uses GtkMenuButton.

GtkMenuButton is a new widget introduced in GTK+ 3.6.

Comment: Related questions: http://askubuntu.com/questions/210195/how-to-update-from-gnome-3-4-1-to-3-6 and http://askubuntu.com/questions/190125/will-gnome-3-6-be-backported-to-12-04/