# How to update from Gnome 3.4.1 to 3.6?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

I use Ubuntu 12.04 with Gnome 3.4.1.

I've tried to upgrade to Gnome 3.6 to no avail.

I added this to my `/etc/apt/sources.list` file:

`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu precise main`

Then I ran

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Then restarted the system.

But when I run:

```
gnome-shell --version
```

It continues to print

```
GNOME Shell 3.4.1
```

What can I do ?

I need to upgrade to 3.6 in order to be able to use an extension that allows the app switcher to only switch between apps in the current workspace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to remove the line that you added to the sources.list.  PPAs are added differently.  From a terminal add the PPA by doing: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3` and `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing`
 .  Then run `sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: I inserted the line in sources.list because when i try to do it with add-apt-repository,  I get this: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 125, in <module>
    ppa_info = get_ppa_info_from_lp(user, ppa_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 84, in get_ppa_info_from_lp
    curl.perform()
pycurl.error: (7, "couldn't connect to host")`

Comment: I'm not sure what that error message means, however I just noticed that the Precise repository of that website only goes to 3.4.  The Quantal repository is 3.6.  You can see the descriptions of the repositories at https://launchpad.net/~gnome3-team/+archive/gnome3  I'll have to look further into upgrading 12.04...

Comment: Oh, I just wanted to add that I wouldn't add the Quantal repository.  There is a good chance that it could break your installation.

Comment: It looks like Manub's answer is right.  The ricotz ppa (https://launchpad.net/~ricotz/+archive/testing) claims to be able to upgrade 12.04 to 3.6.  It does require you to have the gnome3-team repository.  Just so you know, everywhere I looked online said that it was a bad idea and that you should just upgrade to 12.10 if you need 3.6...

Comment: Does QQ come with 3.6 ?

Comment: Yes it does, though Nautilus is held back at the 3.4 version.

Comment: @rft183 will 12.04 eventually get 3.6 or it will get stuck with 3.4 forever?

Answer (score 2):

To update to Gnome 3.6, you need to add these two PPAs:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ricotz/testing
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

- The `dist-upgrade` command is needed because packages that aren't installed must be pulled in as dependencies for the upgrade to work. However, this also makes it possible for packages to be *removed*--which might also be necessary--so it's important to look at what packages, if any, it says will be uninstalled.